# Storekit environment shows [Environment: Xcode]

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto, auto-renewable

Is there an one is facing the same issue?
How can I get resolved on this.
As with [Environment: Xcode] environment subscription gets successful but not getting original transaction id.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks